# How create a aligned Rectangle ( TRect ), equal with mouse coordinates?

Tags: delphi, canvas, rectangles

I'm here for know about how create a `Rect` and `Bitmap` aligned for the same coordinates sent by  mouse, i already have tried several ways but the  screen capture generated by `Bitmap` never is equal to area ( image ) sent by mouse and used to make a hole on Form.

For example:

[image]

This above is a remote desktop and area selected is where have part of vertical menu.

Then, `TBitmap` in client side must be this same content.

So, `TBitmap` in client side must be this same area.

But unfortunately, this is totaly different and image that resulted is in an another position.

[image]

So, here was my last attempt:

*This is the way how mouse sents coordinates:* **( server side )**

```
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
  pbRec: TPaintBox;
  procedure pbRecMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure pbRecMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Integer);
    procedure pbRecMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure pbRecPaint(Sender: TObject);

    private
        { Private declarations }
        FSelecting: Boolean;
        FSelection: TRect;
        function ClientToWindow(const P: TPoint): TPoint;

    .....

    function TForm2.ClientToWindow(const P: TPoint): TPoint;
    begin
      Result := PB1.ClientToScreen(P);
      Dec(Result.X, Left);
      Dec(Result.Y, Top);
    end;

    procedure TForm2.pb1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    begin
      FSelection.Left := X;
      FSelection.Top := Y;
      FSelecting := True;
    end;

    procedure TForm2.pb1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    begin
      if FSelecting then
      begin
        FSelection.Right := X;
        FSelection.Bottom := Y;
        PB1.Invalidate;
      end;
    end;

    procedure TForm2.pb1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    begin
      FSelecting := False;
      FSelection.Right := X;
      FSelection.Bottom := Y;
      PB1.Invalidate;

      FSelection.NormalizeRect;

       Socket.SendText(IntToStr(FSelection.Left) + '§' + IntToStr(FSelection.Top) + '§' + IntToStr(X) + '§' + IntToStr(Y));

    end;

    procedure TForm2.pb1Paint(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      PB1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
      PB1.Canvas.Rectangle(FSelection);
    end;
```

---

```
{ And here is how is received:* **( client side ) }

 type
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
      CS1: TClientSocket;
      procedure CS1Read(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);

     private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

        procedure TForm1.CS1Read(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
         var
           X1, X2, Y1, Y2: Integer;
           List: TStrings;
           FormRegion, HoleRegion: HRGN;
           Bmp: TBitmap;
           R: TRect;
           StrCommand: String;

            begin
             StrCommand := Socket.ReceiveText;

             if Pos('§', StrCommand) > 0 then
              begin

                List := TStringList.Create;
                Bmp :=  TBitmap.Create;
                try

                  ExtractStrings(['§'], [], PChar(StrCommand), List);

                 { Coordinates for area sent by mouse in server side }

                  X1 := StrToIntDef(List[0], 0);
                  Y1 := StrToIntDef(List[1], 0);
                  X2 := StrToIntDef(List[2], 0);
                  Y2 := StrToIntDef(List[3], 0);

             ////////////////////////// THIS IS MY CRITICAL REGION ///////////////////////////

                  R := Rect(X1, Y1, X2, Y2);

                  Bmp.SetSize(R.Width, R.Height);

                  Bmp.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect(0, 0, R.Width, R.Height), Canvas, R);

            ///////////////////////////// END OF CRITICAL REGION //////////////////////////////

                  Bmp.SaveToFile(GetPathToTestExe+'nil.bmp');

                finally
                  List.Free;
                  Bmp.Free;
                end;
              end;

        end;
```

Any suggestion will welcome.

Comment: Are you sure coordinates are *sent* by the mouse? There's nothing in the code that refers to mouse coordinates.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, I edited my question.

Comment: I think you can leave out the socket and create a compilable test case that runs on a single form.

Comment: Use the sample app I gave you in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38267934/62576), and adapt it to try to use the mouse coordinates, and then post it in your question here. As I said in that post, we don't have all of that extra stuff (the outside form, the socket, the variables that aren't in your post) available to us to use. You need to get rid of all the noise and clutter to make your question clear and provide code we can use.

Comment: Also, using the mouse coordinates is only going to work if the monitors are **exactly** the same resolution, using **exactly** the same DPI settings, and are positioned in **exactly** the same screen location. I think you're taking a very difficult approach with the entire *create a hole remotely* approach, personally. Why can't you just create a box on the client of the appropriate size, and then fill it with whatever content you need to draw instead? IOW, the server says "It's a box 250 x 250 pixels", and you draw a box that size, and then fill that box?

Comment: @KenWhite, I'm having success for create a hole on remote Form ( `Form12`), in same position and local that defined in server side independent of resolution of monitors, my trouble as i showed above, is when try make same dimension in `TRect`, the result is a different bmp image if compared to image defined on server side ( position on screen ). Sincerely, i think that my codes above are very clear and show very well the trouble. :-)

Comment: It may show **you** the trouble. The problem is **we** have to see the trouble, and we don't have all of that extra information. How can we copy/paste/compile what you've posted, without having all of the other information that you've not provided? See this post on writing a [mcve], which is exactly what you needed to do for your previous post. I've given you a reasonable base application in that other post to use; you can also use it here to **demonstrate the problem to us**. The problem has to be clear **to us** if you want us to help you.

Comment: If you still can't see what the issue is, do this: Close your project. Do File->New->VCL Forms Application. Copy the code from your post and paste it into that new, blank application. Can you compile and run it to see the problem? If not, then it's not good enough for us to use either. Did you provide clear steps about how to set it up, and do most of it in code (as I did with my answer to your other question), so we can quickly and easily set it up for testing? No, you didn't.

Comment: @KenWhite, on your opinion, i'm making right in this part: `R := Rect(X1, Y1, X2, Y2);` and `Bmp.SetSize(R.Width, R.Height);` and `Bmp.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect(0, 0, R.Width, R.Height), Canvas, R);` ?

Comment: Yes, that appears to be correct. It worked correctly in the code I posted for you before, so I don't know why it wouldn't be working for you now. Unfortunately, I can't compile your code to find out why, because of the reasons I've previously described. If you'd use the code I already gave you and modify it to produce the problem, I could try to figure it out. I did all the work myself once in order to give you that code; I'm not doing it again. :-) I will point out that I mentioned in that post you might need to use `GetRgnBox` to find the correct size of the combined region, though.

Comment: I will try make an better explanation with images.

Comment: OK, but also try to make a better explanation with **code**, too. We don't have `Form12`, and the code you've posted uses `Form1`, and we don't have the client and server code either. If you don't improve the code as well, I'm going to have to vote to close this question as unclear, because you're refusing to provide the code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `Form1` is irrelevante, forget please. And `Form12` is used for set a hole with area for then save on `TBitmap` this area of desktop of client. I edited my question above. :-)

Comment: And as I said, if you didn't also edit the code I would vote to close. I've done that also. Form1 and Form12 are entirely relevant, because **that's what your code uses**.  We don't have either of them, so we can't use your code to help solve the problem. I don't know how many times I' have to say that before you listen. **It's your job to provide the code we can use, not ours. Our half is to use your code to try to answer. Do your half, because we can't do ours without it.** When you edit the code as requested, I'll happily remove that close vote.

Comment: @KenWhite, `Form1` is only to "storage" vcl components. And `Form12` is a simple maximixed Form without nothing. Don't exist more relevant code in these Forms for this question, except these above.

Comment: Form1 and Form12 are entirely relevant, because they're in the code you posted. If you say they're not, then [edit] your code and change it so they don't exist in the post. If you can't do so, they matter and you need to provide the code related to them. I can't find another way to say that **if you want help, you need to edit your code; if you're not willing to do so, then we can't help you**. It's **your responsibility** to provide a [mcve] that we can copy, paste and compile to demonstrate the problem. I'm done here until you do so. Good luck.

Comment: @KenWhite, code edited. I hope that you can understand better now, this is better that i can do about this.

Comment: As promised, I've removed my down and close votes. It's very late here, but if you've not received an answer when I get back here I'll see what I can to to assist. Thank you very much for listening. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite, Thank you, if you want also i can send for you a mini project ( remote assistence tool ) like example with this trouble. I have here. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite, [here](https://www.sendspace.com/file/6fi73f) is the mini project ( only codes ) of a Remote Desktop with this trouble.

Comment: The code that you show (at the moment of writing this), has (at least) two problems: 1) `Bmp` is never created. If that would be true, you would get an access violation error and you wold not get any bitmap file. Ergo the code you have shown is not complete. 2) In `Form2` you record the coordinates as coordinates of the paintbox `pbRec`, but in `Form1`,  when you call `CopyRect` you refer to the **forms canvas** as the source. This can only work if `Form2.pbRec.Canvas` content is exactly the same content as `Form1.Canvas`. Are they?

Comment: @TomBrunberg, you can show an code example here, about how should be the right, based in your comment, please? i don't understood. Also, `Bmp` is generated with sucess, but with different content :-(

Comment: What do you not understand? Read carefully: With 1) I meant that your posted code is missing a line `Bmp := TBitmap.Create;`. Obviously such a line exists in your real code. Please post **real and complete code**. With 2) I said:  in the call to `Bmp.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect(0, 0, R.Width, R.Height), Canvas, R);` the argument `Canvas` refers to the **canvas of the form** (Form1.Canvas). The rectangle `R` is based on coordinates of the paintbox canvas in `Form2` (Form2.pbRec.Canvas). And I asked: Is the contents of these two canvases the same?

Comment: @TomBrunberg, i edited code above, And about ` Is the contents of these two canvases the same?` the answer is: Probably not, because screenshot generated by `Bmp` is equal only in dimensions ( width and height ) but not in content like i said before.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I just wanted to point out the importance of posting precisely the same code that you are using yourself. Regarding 2), I think you lost me, because now I don't get a thing: why are you painting a rectangle on **one image** and copying (with those coordinates) a rectangular area from **another, different image**, and **expecting the resulting copy to be same**? What is a hole in a form?

Comment: @Tom Brunberg, `What is a hole in a form?`: - hole in form is that X1, Y1, X2, Y2, receives mouse coordinate from server sideand make a hole in Form ( and this works perfectly! ) but don't is that i need here now, because this already is solved. And `I think you lost me, because now I don't get a thing: why are you painting a rectangle on one image and copying (with those coordinates) a rectangular area from another, different image, and expecting the resulting copy to be same?` : - You is right, i have made somethings wrong here :-(. "Give me a light please".